# CGContextDrawImage Blending

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontextdrawimage

I am drawing, or should I say "stamping", an image using the `CGContextDrawImage` method in Objective C. The image gets drawn to points that are determined by touch movements. Basically I'm stamping an image to create a "brush" effect. Looks something like this:[image]

I am happy with the results, however when the touch moment slows down the image gets drawn on top of its self and ruins the alpha value I want. Is there a blend technique in which the opacity of the image would not stack on top of each other? Or should I just look at changing my points such that they are not so close together when the movement slows down?

Thanks in advance.